# SVN change property in pre-commit

Tags: svn, properties, hook

I want to have a pre-commit hook check if the current commit is a tag, and if so, check for any svn:externals properties and change them to have revisions if they do not. I have a good idea of how to grep for if they are tags or not, but getting and changing the properties is proving challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a pre-commit hook via svnlook changed (not missing the transaction information via -t)

```
svnlook changed t --copy-info
```

This print out something like this:

```
A + p2/tags/FIRST-TAG/
(from p2/trunk/:r8)
```

So this is a tag...

Check for properties is fine as well...

```
svnlook proplist t /p2/tags/FIRST-TAG
```

So far so good. You can now check the contents of an svn:externals.

But you should never modify anything within a transaction. Never Never do this.
The best thing is to simply abort the operation (giving back non zero) and give an explanation about this via stderr output.

Comment: It is possible to alter transaction in post-commit hook as revision. Check for necessary revision properties and alter them.

Comment: If you add a *new* file, can you check svn:eol-style property on it using pre-commit hook?